# Is there a way in Isabelle to define Truth Tables?

Tags: isabelle

I Tried with new types, records and recursive functions but to no avail. I need truth tables in order to prove functional completeness of a set of connectives. How should I do that?
I only know that the type most closely related to truth tables is `bool list list`: which is not enough since i want them to have n columns and 2^n rows, with n a natural number.

EDIT: I am following Elliot Mendelson Proof of this theorem 
**Conjunction, Disjunction And Negation are a set of functional complete operator**

The proof goes along these lines: first we suppose to have a function with n arguments ( n truth values of the n variables) and a single truth-value.
This function determines a truth table. Now, for each row i, we build a C_i boolean expression which consist of the conjuction of propositions U_j, where U_j is equal to A_j if the jth variable have the value True, else is equal to Not A_j. Next we pick up the disjuction of all these C_i where the function assumes the Truth-Value = True.
This boolean expression generates a truth table which is identical to the function's truth table.

I've tried, first, to define truth table, which i managed to do with a simple definition:

```
primrec max_col :: "bool list list ⇒ nat" where
"max(Nil) = 0"|
"max(x # ts) = (if size(x)>max_col(ts) then size(x) else max_col(ts))"

primrec confr_T :: "bool list list  ⇒ bool list" where
"confr_T([]) = []" |
"confr_T(x # xs) = (if size(x) = max(xs) then True # confr_T(xs) else False# confr_T(xs))"

definition T_build :: "bool list list ⇒ bool list list" where
"T_build t ≡ if   confr_T(t) = gen_True(size(confr_T(t))) ∧ size(t) = 2^(max_col(t)) then t else [] #[]"
```

Long story short, i defined two functions, max (which defines the maximum lenght of the row of type `bool list list`) and confr_T (which checkes if all rows have the same lenght).
Equipped with these two function I provived a definition for truth tables, which should have equal sized rows and a number of rows equal to 2^n where n is the number of columns.
I used here a gen_True function which generates a bool list with all True values, in order to confront this list with the one generated by Confr_T.

But from this poin on, i am struggling to build up my demostration. I've made some attempt but it seems wrong to me.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is `n`? Do you want your type to contain tables for all `n` or just for one fixed `n`?

Comment: As far as I get it, you want to prove that for every function that maps valuations of variables to truth values, there is a term built from your set of connectives characterizing this function? Do you have your language of connectives as a datatype in Isabelle? Then, this would seem possible to me without any additional special data structures for truth tables.

Comment: @ManuelEberl Yes i want my type to contain all tables for all `n`.

Comment: @BenKeks I managed to build up truth tables in the end, but the definition comes with cumbersome notation and a  lot of functions with it. I defined a function which takes a bool list list argument type: if this one is of the kind of truth tables, it will return the argument, else will return the Nil Constructor for list. How would i prove such a thing without truth tables? Also i managed to define my own language for connectives as a datatype. From there, though, i thought i needed truth tables in order to complete the proof

Comment: @NikolajDiRondò Great that you've found a solution! :) It's hard to give you direct answers from the limited amount of info you've provided. (Ideally, you would post some key excerpts from your definitions. And maybe also some more concrete listing for ways you tried.)

Comment: I still don't *really* understand why `bool list list` is not sufficient. But as @BenKeks said, it is just impossible to say what the best representation is without more context.

Comment: I am sorry . I provided more context editing the post. I hope it is intelligible.

Comment: @BenKeks Here, it is enough context?